# How do I linq like query with Dictionary in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, linq, typescript, dictionary

There is interface of dictionary:

```
interface Dictionary<T> {
    [Key: string]: T;
}
```

And some class that counts daily repeating of some exersizes:

```
export class ClassName {
   DailyReapeatCount: Dictionary<number> = {};
}
```

Let's initialize it:

```
let myClass = new ClassName();
        myClass.DailyReapeatCount['exersize_01'] = 3;
        myClass.DailyReapeatCount['exersize_02'] = 4;
        // ... and so on
```

Then I need to check if it has any exersize with DailyReapeatCount  more then 5:

```
// pseudo code there
let isAnyExist = myClass.DailyReapeatCount.some(p => p.value > 5);
```

There I get ts notification:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type
>   Number has no compatible call signatures."

How do I get this query?

Comment: Can't you use `Dictionary.Count`? (sorry for the horrible identifiers, but you chose them)` myClass.Where(myClassName => myClassName.Count > 5).Any()`? Or the jav equivalents for `Any`

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse it's okay for identifiers, I understand what you mean. If I add index signature: **export class ClassName { [x: string]: any; ... }** and do  **myClass.Where(myClassName => myClassName.Count > 5).Any()** I get `TypeError: myClass.Where is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use standard [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (it's the same as `Dictionary` in C#):

```
const dictionary = new Map<string, number>([
  ["one", 1], 
  ["two", 2],
  ["five", 5],
]);

const values = Array.from(dictionary.values());
const isExist = values.some(v => v < 5);
console.log(isExist);

// In addition you can do dictionary-based things like:
console.log(dictionary.has("five")); // check is key exists
```